# DLLs and out of memory exception

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment

I am working on matlab deploytool which generates a .Net dll. When I call the function from the dll it crashes because out of memory exception. It runs correctly  without any exceptions in matlab. How avoid this excetion?

Comment: how do you call the function without matlab?

Comment: can't you show the stacktrace? is the exception thrown from within matlab functions in the dll?

Comment: yes, the exception is thrown from a matlab function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, work on Windows 64-bit and this memory exception will be gone.